# cordova 3.4 with xcode 5.1 won´t build with latest file-transfer plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I updated my cordova app to 3.4.0-0.1.3. I have xcode 5.1. In my app I use a brunch of plugins an rm/add all of them. `cordova plugins list` reports the following:

```
[ 'com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin',
  'org.apache.cordova.camera',
  'org.apache.cordova.console',
  'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.dialogs',
  'org.apache.cordova.file',
  'org.apache.cordova.file-transfer',
  'org.apache.cordova.geolocation',
  'org.apache.cordova.globalization' ]
```

After that I tried to build in xcode and got a lot of errors (47), but I did my homework an found a lot of helpful answers like these http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/ which helped me reduce the issues down to 2. Below are the error messages form the command line, because I´m not allowed (by now) to post screenshots. They are quite similar to the one in xcode:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVFilesystemURL", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVFileTransfer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
  Ld build/emulator/Appname.app/Appname normal i386
(1 failure)
Error: /Users/username/Documents/cordova/appname/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

Because the error message refers to CDVFileTransfer.o, I tried to uninstall the File-Transfer Pluging an build again. Now I got this lovely `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **` Message. After reinstall the plugin, the build fail again.

I did a lot of research but did´t find anything related, except the following, but I´m not sure if this cause the problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6212 Can anyone confirm?

Did anyone running the newest cordova (3.4.0-0.1.3) with new xcode (5.1) and the file-transfer plugin (0.4.2)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.  Cordova 3.4.0-0.1.2 and xcode 5.1 - Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not jet. I will report here if I find a solution...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have had the same error. I solved it by checking the files compiled by xcode.
In my case CDVFile.m was not in the list.

I invit you to verify if the plugin *.m files are well added to the compilation file list.

Comment: In `Build Phases > Compile Sources` CDVFileTransfer.m is there but CDVFile.m was missing. I added it to the list right above CDVFileTransfer.m which increase the errors from 2 to 4, but the error messages suggested me to also add CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.m and CDVLocalFilesystem.m with were also missing. Now my builds work again! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Thanks!  This answer and the comment above did the trick for me too.

Comment: Making sure all the sources are present in the `Build Phases > Compile Sources` list is essential. You can find the `Build Phases` panel after selecting your project's Target. (This issue got me after upgrading to Cordova 3.5.0.)

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the File plugin only, and re-installing (after you get the error).
For me to properly repro this, please also provide the order of installation of the plugins, it may provide a clue to the bug.

Comment: Uninstalling only the File plugin seems not to work. I get the message `No dangling plugins to remove.` and the plugin still shown up with `cordova plugin list`. I have already tried to uninstall both (first file-transfer) and then reinstall them (first file) without luck.

Comment: Had the same problem with cordova 3.3.0. Looking at the diffs after removing & re-adding plugins it seems, that the SystemConfiguration.framework & AudioToolbox.framework get removed, but not re-added. Adding them manually solved it

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Here's what worked for me:

1. Uninstall file-transfer
2. Uninstall file
3. Re-install file-transfer

I tried every other order, but that is the only way it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks shekki25! I have tried this uninstall/reinstall order as well. But the only solution was to add the missing build sources. Maybe that was a bug in cordova 3.4.0 and 3.4.1 fixed it. I remember to read something about it, but I´m not sure...

Comment: I guess you forgot to install the file plugin as 3th step since file-transfer relies on it? So:
1. Uninstall file-transfer
2. Uninstall file
3. Re-install file
4. Re-install file-transfer ??