# Cordova File plugin breaks my app

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I just installed the cordova file plugin and it completely breaks my application with this error:

```
ERROR: Method 'requestAllPaths:' not defined in Plugin 'File'
```

After googling for several variations of this topic I wasn't able to find anything that addresses this issue. Any ideas?

I am using Cordova 3.5.0 with the file plugin added like this:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

I tried adding the optional configuration described in the readme on github but that didn't change anything.

This is the error code that I am getting when I run:

```
cordova run ios

[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
    "File1936338184",
    "File",
    "requestAllPaths",
    [

    ]
]
```

I am absolutely clueless as to why this is happening or where.

Comment: Can you paste the code where the `requestAllPaths:` call is being made.

Comment: That's what I would like to know because I am not the one making it. The App was running just fine and I installed this plugin more out of curiosity than necessity, I guess it's an updated version, and then the application loads but doesn't initialize correctly after the DeviceReady event.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the App you are making a call to **requestAllPaths**.
As far as the **File API** documentation goes there is no such method as **requestAllPaths**
There is an API called **requestFileSystem**.
Hope it helps to debug your app

**edit1:**
You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470166/android-cordova-3-5-0-deviceready-not-firing-after-installing-media-plugin) for a similar issue.

Comment: I guess downgrading fixed it. Doh. Thank you.

Comment: Which kinda sucks because I was hoping to use all the cool stuff described here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error happens if the plugin was **already** added to your project : in that case, it seems that the Cordova build process only updates the javascript interface but not the underlying native iOS sources, which explains the missing code :(

To fix it, you should remove the plugin beforing adding it :

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

Be aware though that you might run in some additional issues : even if the files are properly updated in your platforms/ios/project_name/plugins directory, they might not be properly referenced in xcode => cf. [cordova 3.4 with xcode 5.1 won´t build with latest file-transfer plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836347/cordova-3-4-with-xcode-5-1-won%C2%B4t-build-with-latest-file-transfer-plugin)

Hope it helps,
Cheers,
D.

Comment: I tried doing that a few times and it never worked, in the end I even got build errors and the app was completely broken. However, after setting up a completely new project and adding the plugins one by one via CLI and then copying in my existing code, everything worked like a charm.